# Mutliselect checkbox in a list in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So i have a todos list and i need to add a checkbox for each todo and then to get the **todo.title** when that checkbox is selected

My **application.hbs**

```
        {{#each model as |todo|}}
      <li class="list_shopping li_num_0_1">

                            <div class="col_md_3_list">
                                <div class="cont_text_date">

                                        {{input type="checkbox"}}               
                                        {{todo.title}}


                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
```

My **application.js**

```
 export default Route.extend({
      newTodo: "",
      actions: {

      model() {
        return this.store.findAll("todo");
      }
    });
```

Any ideas please? 
I ve tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/
https://ember-twiddle.com/b0e9cab25764e50c122ca482776bdae3?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

Comment: what version of Ember are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is easy. what you need to do is capture the event which is triggering from the input of checkbox. then in the controller you need to catch that event and change the attribute of checked=true then it will get the state of checked and you can create a observer to handle the property of the model that you are listing out. example

```
Todos have todo[] 
todo has a property todo.isselected
```

when you are putting into array you can do as follows

```
  {{input type='checkbox' id='todo.id' checked=todo.isselected}}
```

in controller, have an observer to `todo.isselected` ( model.isselected - what ever the local model name you use ) 
example

```
captureNameWhenSelected: observer ("todo.isselected", function(){
     arrayOfNames.pushObject( this.get('todo.id') ,this.get('todo.name'));
})
```

hope this will help to resolve your question